# Cannot enter "::before" for li tag when editing a Wordpress page

Tags: pages, editor

I want to enter into my page content, under text mode editor, the HTML syntax which is `::before` for my `li` tag.

But when saved, Wordpress automatically changes that to **"::before" WITH quotes**. I don't want those quotes. How can I keep my `::before` intact?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to manually enter it? The `::before` and `::after` are there even without declaration.

```
li::before {
    some rules...
}

li::after {
    some rules...
}
```

[Here is an article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) that describes it.

Comment: I "debug" the UI of Wordpress code and saw such `::before` in the HTML so I asked. Thank you for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write this syntax directly to plain HTML code. `::berfore` element is added to HTML tag only when it is defined in CSS stylesheet (like denis.stoyanov wrote).